# C language: How is swapping pointers different from swapping the value pointed to?

Tags: c, pointers, swap

```
int a=5; b=7;
int *pa=&a, *pb=&b;
```

How is swapping the values of a and b different from swapping the values of the pointers i.e `pa` and `pb` (not `*pa` and `*pb`)? Is the result not same in both cases?

When do we have to use pointer swapping than?

I have an example in the book that uses pointer swapping with an array of strings i.e `char*`[]. This is done as a part of sorting mechanism. The swapping function carries out pointer swapping for the `char* []` type variable that stores the strings. I do not understand why the function swap is of form `void swap(char** , char**)`.

I can't find any explanation for this elsewhere thus my question.

:( How does `swap(int*& a, int*& b)` compare to `swap(char** a,char** b)`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why swapping variable values using pointers is preferred is because it avoids **copying large amounts of memory**. Any memory copy takes time so keeping the amount of memory copying to a minimum makes algorithms run faster.

**How does memory copying become an issue?**

Consider the following pseudo-code, which can swap two values of any type *in-place*:

```
tempValue = value1;      /* first memory copy */
value1    = value2;      /* second memory copy */
value2    = tempvalue;   /* third memory copy */
```

In your original question, you swapped two *integers*. Assuming that an integer is 4 bytes in width, then the above pseudo-code will swap the two integers in three copy operations. Total memory copied: 12 bytes. If we assume that a pointer is also 4 bytes in width, then swapping the pointer values will also require copying 12 bytes of memory. In this case the amount of memory copied to swap the values is the same as swapping the pointers. In this case either method will give the same performance.

Now consider this code fragment:

```
typedef struct _mystruct
{
    char buffer[128];   /* size of structure becomes at least 128 bytes */

} MYSTRUCT, *PMYSTRUCT;

MYSTRUCT value1, value2;

PMYSTRUCT pValue1 = &value1;
PMYSTRUCT pValue2 = &value2;
```

The size of `MYSTRUCT` is at least 128 bytes. Using the pseudo-code above to swap the values of `value1` and `value2` will require three memory copies of 128 bytes, or 384 bytes in total. If, on the other hand, I swap the values using the two pointers `pValue1` and `pValue2`, assuming a pointer is 4 bytes wide, the number of bytes copied during the swap is the same as our integer example above; only 12 bytes. This, when compared to 384 bytes if you don't use pointers, is very quick and will perform much better.

That is why `char**` is used as the parameter to the string-swapping function. The length of the strings being swapped is not known, and because swapping values means copying memory, long strings could slow the performance considerably. Using pointers means that the performance of the swapping will remain the same, regardless of the length of the strings being swapped.

Answer (score 1):

`swap(int*& a, int*& b)` is not C but C++, it is pass by reference rather than actual pointers.
With this example you wouldn't understand passing pointer or passing variable.

Think about how will you swap 2 integers and 2 strings i,e.

```
int a=10, b=20; 
char *s1="ABC", *s2="PQRS";
swap_int(a, b);
swap_str(s1, s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "[ ]" to denote a memory block that stores some value:

Before swapping:

```
a: [5]
b: [7]
```

After swapping:

```
a: [7]
b: [5]
```

Then accessing a would give 7.

Before swapping:

```
pa: [&a] (that is, the address of a)
pb: [&b]
```

After swapping:

```
pa: [&b]
pb: [&a]
```

Then accessing pa would result in the address of b, and dereferencing (*pa) will get the value of b.

For char **, I think the sorting procedure you describe is to sort an array of "char *", which is classical string in C. You can see a "char *" entity as a "string" object. And "char **" is "string *", which should be considered as an array of "string" object. Then you can depict the assignments involved in the sorting like the "a" and "b" scenario above.